# how to establish a communication between obd2 wifi and the pi 3 (raspbian)

Tags: raspbian

i want to recieve data from my obd2(ELM 327) wifi interface  to my pi into the screen, i can connect my pi to the "WIFI_OBD" but i don't know how to send a command throw the screen and receiving data.

if the question is not clear you can watch this video where the guy have OBD with bluethoot interface, so i want to do the same work with wifi interface.
thank you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DABytIdutKk

Comment: Locate Wi-Fi network, created by ELM327 OBDII adapter and connect to it.

Usually, it’s called “OBDII”, “OBD2”, “WIFI_OBDII” or something like that. Sometimes its name has something familiar with your adapter brand (e.g. VGate adapters usually have “VLINK” network name).

Comment: @MatsK You should make your comment an answer.